# VS code terminal is not running live code, having to save the file each time I edit the code

Tags: visual-studio

I'm new to coding and was trying to use the terminal in VS code to execute some simple lines of code, but each time I enter the command "python file.py" it runs the code, but it runs the saved code and each time I make changes in my code I have to save the file in order for the terminal to execute the code I want it to which is super inconvenient compared to other IDEs like pycharm.

I tried running the code in output tab rather the terminal, but the output tab doesn't take in input so I can't use the input() command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to run the script in the terminal tab it will only run the .py file that is saved in that directory. At the top right there is a 'play button' that will save python file and then run it with the output in the terminal. This would allow you to use the input() also.